# Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ui'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to start up a very basic web app with Django and getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ui'`

My django project is `frontend_project` and the app is `ui`

Tree:

```
front_end
├── front-end/Pipfile
├── front-end/Pipfile.lock
├── front-end/README.md
├── front-end/db.sqlite3
├── front-end/frontend_project
│   ├── front-end/frontend_project/__init__.py
│   ├── front-end/frontend_project/
│   │   └──front-end/frontend_project/ui
│   │       ├── front-end/frontend_project/ui/__init__.py
│   │       ├── front-end/frontend_project/ui/admin.py
│   │       ├── front-end/frontend_project/ui/apps.py
│   │       ├── front-end/frontend_project/ui/migrations
│   │       │   └── front-end/frontend_project/ui/migrations/__init__.py
│   │       ├── front-end/frontend_project/ui/models.py
│   │       ├── front-end/frontend_project/ui/tests.py
│   │       ├── front-end/frontend_project/ui/urls.py
│   │       └── front-end/frontend_project/ui/views.py
│   ├── front-end/frontend_project/settings.py
│   ├── front-end/frontend_project/urls.py
│   └── front-end/frontend_project/wsgi.py
└── front-end/manage.py
```

Installed_apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ui.apps.UiConfig',
]
```

And my `frontend_project` urls.py looks like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('ui.urls')),
]
```

`ui` urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import homePageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', homePageView, name='home'),
]
```

EDIT: I removed the apps directory and placed the UI app under the project directory - Still experiencing the same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ui'`

I'm just trying to get a simple web app working for right now and my python version is 3.6.7 and pipenv.

Thanks all!

Comment: What is the value of `sys.path`?

Comment: it returns empty, so i guess that it isn't set... should this env variable be set automatically by python?

Comment: @JohnGordon also, I am using pipenv

Comment: You probably need to pre-pend "apps" in your INSTALLED_APPS settings. You have everything underneath a directory called "apps" (which isn't standard AFAIK) but that's probably what's going on here. If you brought all those files up a level and deleted "apps" it would probably work just fine.

Comment: @theWanderer4865 I previously had it directory above apps with the same issue

Comment: What is in the app config for the path? In the apps.py file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured your project in an atypical way. **While not absolutely required, the most straightforward (and most common) way to structure the project is to include your project apps in the root directory, which is the directory that contains manage.py.**

In your case, your 'ui' app directory would be located at front_end/front_end/. (Not under /front_end/front_end/front_end/frontend_project/)

IF you want to keep the project structure that you currently have, there are a additional configuration changes necessary, including subclassing AppConfig (see below).

**You will also need to use a dotted path to your application urlconf from your root UrlConf (This is the configuration step that you missed that is likely causing the error).**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('frontend_project.ui.urls')), <--- here
]
```

In your case, by defining a direct path to `'ui.apps.UiConfig'` in INSTALLED_APPS, Django looks for the configuration in the dotted path to the AppConfig subclass for that application which is located in apps.py.

```
# ui/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class UiConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'ui'
```

Comment: If i have done what? ```'ui.apps.UiConfig'``` is in my settings already and my apps.pt already looks exactly like that, so what are you suggesting hat i do?

Comment: Also, I reverted back to the way I had the directory structure in the past ```frontend_project/ui/``` and having the same error: ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ui'```

Comment: move it up to dir with manage.py --> front_end/front_end  so that dir would include: frontend_project/, ui/, README.md, manage.py, db.sql..., Pip..., Pipfile.lock; frontend_project/ would include settings.py, urls.py, wsgi.py, __init__.py; ui/ would include admin.py, apps.py, models.py, tests.py, urls.py, views.py, __init__.py, migrations/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create an `__init__.py` file at `front-end/frontend_project/apps/`

Comment: I had the ecact same issue what my directory structure was ```front-end/frontend_project/ui``` ... I reverted it back to that and i'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Import urls.py file of Ui app in frontend_project urls.py file.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from ui import urls

urlpatterns = [
      path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
      path('', include('ui.urls')),
]
```

Comment: [pylint] Unable to import 'ui' [E0401]

Comment: @aphexlog your app must in root directory.

Comment: My app now sits at ```frontend_project/ui``` with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by moving ui to root as suggested, Thanks everyone!

But I thought that the directory structure was supposed to be `project_name/app_name` .. apparently, the app is actually supposed to sit in the same directory as the project?